# Neo4j/cypher: Return id as property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got this super simple cypher query for my juicy graph database of two nodes:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

And it's returning the two nodes as such:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "columns": [
            "n"
        ],
        "data": [
            {
                "row": [
                    {
                        "name": "node 1",
                        "description": "This is my first node."
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "row": [
                    {
                        "name": "node 2",
                        "description": "This is my second node."
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"errors": []
}
```

I was kind of expecting to get the id out as a property with "name" and "description". How can i get it in there? I know I can go something like:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n, id(n)
```

But that would put the id outside the object and I don't want that.

Comment: Id in Neo4j are not reliable. They could change in time. It's better to use your own property as Node identificator or use GraphAware UUID plugin - https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map `{foobar:42}`and collection structures in Cypher `[1,2,3]`

so you can return:

```
RETURN {id:id(n), labels: labels(n), data: n}
```

or you can use

```
{"statement":"match (n) return n","resultDataContents":["graph"]}
```

as additional parameter to your POST request.

Comment: I was rather looking for RETURN { id:id(n), name:n.name, description:n.description }, but this helped me understand how the return statement works. (As a side note for other seekers: I originally wanted to use the ID as the unique identifier in the app I am building, but as MicTech pointed out in his comment above this is not good. Neo4j might for example reuse the ID when a node is deleted. Apparently it's better to generate your own unique id:s).